# Added undefined in for loop at end

Tags: jquery, javascript

When I populate a dropdown by using for loop and json object ,it adds undefined  option in dropdown at end .

```
 for (var i in PriceRanges[purpose]) {
        var r = PriceRanges[purpose][i];
        html += '<option value="' + r.id + '">' + r.text + '</option>';
}
```

Where PriceRanges is my json object.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: can you put in your JSON object? We need to see the properties

Comment: Please console `PriceRange[purpose]` and post the object content.

Comment: Is `PriceRanges[purpose]` an array or an object?  Chances are that you're getting a value for `r` that isn't the type you expect it to be so `r.text` is `undefined`.  This is probably caused because one value of `i` is not what you expect.  If `PriceRanges[purpose]` is an array, then you should be iterating it with `for (var i = 0, len =  PriceRanges[purpose].length; i < len; i++)` rather than how you're doing it.

Comment: Please provide the PriceRanges object. Also, take a closer look for yourself at this object by putting console.log(PriceRanges) somewhere.

Comment: check for undefied as i did in my answer might resolve your issue

Comment: @AlbertoLeón PriceRanges json is PriceRanges: { "sale": [{ "id": 25, "min": 0, "max": 700000, "text": "Below 7 lacs" }, { "id": 26, "min": 700001, "max": 1500000, "text": "7 - 15 lacs" }, { "id": 27, "min": 1500001, "max": 2500000, "text": "15 - 25 lacs" }, { "id": 28, "min": 2500001, "max": 4000000, "text": "25 - 40 lacs" }, { "id": 29, "min": 4000001, "max": 6000000, "text": "40 - 60 lacs" }]

Comment: @ChandrasenSingh what is the vlaue of Purpose?

Comment: @AlbertoLeón here value of purpose is 'sale'

Comment: @ChandrasenSingh: You're iterating over an array, don't use `for...in` and you should be all right. Check the second part of my answer. The undefined comes from the fact that `for in` includes the length property, so the last iteration amounts to `PriceRanges[purpose][length].id`, which is undefined, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check for undfied like this and than add

```
for (var i in PriceRanges[purpose])
 {
         var r = PriceRanges[purpose][i];
         if (typeof r != "undefined") 
         {
            if (typeof r.id != "undefined"
                  && typeof r.text != "undefined")
            html += '<option value="' + r.id + '">' + r.text + '</option>';
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not defined **var html**  , it will **be equal to undefined** .. So when you append that to the string the undefined is still in the concatenated string ..

So try this

```
var html = '';
for (var i in PriceRanges[purpose]) {
        var r = PriceRanges[purpose][i];
        html += '<option value="' + r.id + '">' + r.text + '</option>';
}
```

This should solve your problem....

Comment: Nah, this isn't the problem: _An undefined option is added at the end_ ==> html will probably be set to `<select id="foo">` before the object (well, I suspect it's an array) is iterated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side, you should *always* check the property owner of any key in a `for in` loop:

```
for (var i in PriceRanges[purpose])
{
    if (PriceRanges[purpose].hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
        html += '<option value="' + PriceRanges[purpose][i].id + '">'
                + PriceRanges[purpose][i].text + '</option>';
    }
}
```

But this does look to me like you're iterating over an array, in which case: use `for`, not `for in`, because the last `i` in `for in` on an array will be the length property...

```
for (var i=0;i<PriceRanges[purpose].length;i++)
{
    html += '<option value="' + PriceRanges[purpose][i].id + '">'
            + PriceRanges[purpose][i].text + '</option>';
}
```

Of course, to be extra, super-duper safe, you should add an if to both loops:

```
if (PriceRanges[purpose][i].id && PriceRanges[purpose][i].text)
```

To avoid using properties that don't exist (and will therefore return undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I think using jQuery's each function you can control the colection

```
var html = "";

$.each(PriceRanges.sale, function() {

        html += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.text + '</option>';
});
```